# Calling some jQuery on page load

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax load function that uses jQuery when an `<a><a/>` is clicked further up the page.

This also triggers a cookie to be planted, so that the opened document remains if the user comes back.

```
<a id="request" onClick="createCookie('foobar')">Click me</a>

<div id="result"  class="functions">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup ({
                cache: false
        });
        var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

        var loadUrl<?=$request->id?> = "viewrequest.php?id=<?=$request->id?>";
        $("#display").click(function(){
                $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
                        var loaded<?=$request->id?> = 1
        });
</script>
</div>
```

That works fine.  What I want to do is use php to see if the cookie exists (easy).

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['foobar']))
```

and then, trigger the AJAX.

That's the bit I can't work out how to do.  I assume the id="request" in the < a > triggers the AJAX when clicked, but I can't think how to do it on load inside the php if loop.

Comment: I've solved it, 

    <? if.... { ?>
    <script>
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
                            var loaded = 1
    <script>
    <? } ?>

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (untested, but the logic is good)

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['foobar'])): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

        var loadUrl<?=$request->id?> = "viewrequest.php?id=<?=$request->id?>";
        $("#display").click(function(){
                $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
                        var loaded<?=$request->id?> = 1
        });
    });
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //code
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code
});
```

depending on when you actually need it to execute.

window.load will wait for the full DOM to be loaded.

document ready doesn't wait for all requests to complete

Comment: I need it to trigger what's currently inside the <script> tags

Comment: Then wrap the contents inside a function and call that. You can't say "go execute this script block". but you can say "do_this();"

Comment: I've solved it, <? if.... { ?> <script> $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); var loaded = 1 <script> <? } ?>

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't directly trigger javascript. Remember that PHP executes on the server, while Javascript executes on the client.

At most, PHP can output a small snippet of javascript while the page is being built, and embed a function call into that snippet>

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['foobar'])) {
    echo <<<EOL
<script type="text/javascript">
    the_cookie_is_set();
</script>
EOL;
}
?>
```

which would then run your function when the page is loaded/processed by the client.

However, since you're using AJAX, that implies you've had Javascript send something to the server and get a response. Why not use the response handler to trigger that function?

Comment: I believe that the AJAX in the JS on my page is only called when the < a > is clicked as its id="request" corresponds to that in the AJAX, so I need to do the same thing inside a php if loop and onLoad rather than onClick

Comment: I've solved it, <? if.... { ?> <script> $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); var loaded = 1 <script> <? } ?>